# CSS Animation Keyframe Not Working

Tags: css, animation

The gradient on this works just fine, but I cannot get the animation keyframe to work. I have it working on codepen at http://codepen.io/Saucy/pen/peVwKR but cannot make it work at https://www.Sauc.io/test. Why? I've spent 6 hours on it now and still cannot figure it out.

```
#main {

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(
to bottom right,  
#2C3E50, #FD746C, 
#FF8235, #ffff1c, 
#92FE9D, #00C9FF, 
#a044ff, #e73827);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 1000% 1000%;
-webkit-animation: gradient 240s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: gradient 240s ease infinite;
-ms-animation: gradient 240s ease infinite;
-o-animation: gradient 240s ease infinite;
-animation: gradient 240s ease infinite;


@-webkit-keyframes gradient
{
0%{background-position:0% 0%}
50%{background-position:100% 100%}
100%{background-position:0% 0%}
}

@-moz-keyframes gradient
{
0%{background-position:0% 0%}
50%{background-position:100% 100%}
100%{background-position:0% 0%}
}

@-ms-keyframes gradient
{  0%{background-position:0% 0%}
50%{background-position:100% 100%}
100%{background-position:0% 0%}
}

@keyframes gradient { 
0%{background-position:0% 0%}
50%{background-position:100% 100%}
100%{background-position:0% 0%}
}
 }
```

Comment: https://www.sauc.io/test  is working for me in Chrome.

Comment: yes, on the codepen it works, but on my website it doesn't. Are you talking about the codepen or my website?

Comment: yes it works but the animation isn't working, it's only animated on codepen

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Were u able to solve this?

Comment: Sort of, but not all the way. It works but the transition back into the whole animation is sloppy. May start working on it again here soon.